# Design base class for derived classes with functions having different signatures

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

```
class B {
public:
    virtual void foo(?);
}
class D1 : public B {
public:
    void foo(T1*);
}
class D2 : public B {
public:
    void foo(T2*);
}

B* b1 = new D1();
B* b2 = new D2();
```

T1 and T2 may not be related.

How do I design the classes such that called b1 and b2 call the correct foo with correct type?

Can use upto c++14.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to do that.  What should `b1->foo(new T2)` do?

Comment: b1->foo(new T2) should give a compilation error.

Comment: But `b1` is a pointer to `B`.  And `B::foo` has to somehow accept `T1*` and `T2*`.  Consider `B* b = rand() ? new B1 : new B2; b->foo(new T1);`  Compile time is long past when the type of object pointed to by `b` is decided.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?   As specified, the problem is impossible in C++ ... but there may well be a way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: What arguments do you want to call `b->foo` with?

Answer (score 0):

The way you want it to perform can be achieved by the following code, but doesn't seem to me like a good design. So, you need to rethink about your design.

```
class T1 { 
public:
    void f() {
        cout << "Calls T1::f\n";
    }
};
class T2 {
public:
    void g() {
        cout << "Calls T2::g\n";
    }
};
class B {
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
    virtual void foo(T1* t) {/* throw some exception maybe! */}
    virtual void foo(T2* t) {/* throw some exception maybe! */}
};
class D1 : public B {
public:
    void foo(T1* t) {
        t->f();
    }
};
class D2 : public B {
public:
    void foo(T2* t) {
        t->g();
    }
};
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/G85prX)!

Answer (score 0):

```
class B {
public:
    template<class Derived, class T>
    void foo(T &&x) {
        //Crashes if can't be converted, test for nullptr maybe
        dynamic_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo(x);
    }
}

class D1 : public B<D1> {
public:
    void foo(T1*);
}
class D2 : public B<D2> {
public:
    void foo(T2*);
}

B * b1 = new D1();
B * b2 = new D2();

T1 t1;
b1->foo<D1> (&t1);
```

Since `T1` and `T2` have no relationship and don't belong to the same class tree, then it means that when calling `foo` you *know* which child class of `B` `b1` is of. So you just give that child class as a template parameter.

Another solution is a C-style cast to `void*`: (not advised in C++)

```
class B {
public:
    template<class T>
    void foo(T *x) {
        foo_handler(reinterpret_cast<void*>(x));
    }
protected:
    virtual void foo_handler(void*) = 0;
}

class D1 : public B<D1> {
public:
    void foo(T1*);
private:
    void foo_handler(void *x) {foo(reinterpret_cast<T1*>(x));}
}
class D2 : public B<D2> {
public:
    void foo(T2*);
private:
    void foo_handler(void *x) {foo(reinterpret_cast<T2*>(x));}
}

B * b1 = new D1();
B * b2 = new D2();

T1 t1;
b1->foo(&t1);
```